# String.prototype.replaceAll() not working

Tags: javascript

I need to replace all the string in a variable.

```js
var a = "::::::";
a = a.replace(":", "hi");
console.log(a);
```

The above code replaces only the first string i.e..`hi::::::`
I used `replaceAll` but it's not working.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

**Update:** All recent versions of major browsers, as well as NodeJS 15+ now support `replaceAll`

**Original:**

There is no `replaceAll` in JavaScript: the error console was probably reporting an error.

Instead, use the `/g` ("match globally") modifier with a regular expression argument to `replace`:

```js
const a = "::::::";
const replaced = a.replace(/:/g,"hi");
console.log(replaced);
```

The is covered in [MDN: String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (and elsewhere).

Comment: why do this code not working var a=":):)::::";
a = a.replace(/:)/g,"hi");
alert(a);

Comment: @VishnuChid  Because `/:)/g` is an invalid regular expression literal (it will result in a SyntaxError due to the "extra" closing parenthesis). Try `/:\)/g` instead. Please read the error messages and be precise about error messages - "not working" and "doesn't work" are very vague.

Comment: i get  SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list for /:\)/g , please help , and what is the topic i should read about for using slashes ??

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: It's been many years since this answer was made, and replaceAll is now included in MDN documentation and the ECMA-262 (2021) spec, but replaceAll still isn't widely available in all browsers. Firefox is including it starting with version 77. Hopefully this update saves someone a few minutes of confusion.

Comment: What's that then? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: @mgPePe read comment above.

Comment: Node JS does NOT support replaceAll !!!

Comment: show this answer when testers don't believe devs "It's been many years since this answer was made, and replaceAll is now included in MDN documentation and the ECMA-262 (2021) spec, but replaceAll still isn't widely available in all browsers. Firefox is including it starting with version 77. Hopefully this update saves someone a few minutes of confusion." ...

Comment: ```String.prototype.replaceAll = (search, replacement) => {
    const target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
```

Comment: As of node 15, node supports replaceAll.

Answer (score 84):

There is no `replaceAll` function in JavaScript.

You can use a regex with a global identifier as shown in pst's answer:

`a.replace(/:/g,"hi");`

An alternative which some people prefer as it eliminates the need for regular expressions is to use JavaScript's `split` and `join` functions like so:

```
a.split(":").join("hi");
```

It is worth noting the second approach is however slower.

Comment: update 2021:
`String.prototype.replaceAll()` is now a valid function in JS but has no support in Node yet.
Example:
`
let p = 'The dog ate my homework. Bad dog.';

p.replaceAll('dog', 'goat');

console.log(p); // 'The goat ate my homework. Bad goat.'
`

Comment: https://2ality.com/2019/12/string-prototype-replaceall.html introduced in ES2021

Comment: Node 15 now supports replaceAll.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript clearly shows that there is too a 'replaceAll ' in JavaScript